# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't show up in update-manager

Tags: 17.04, update-manager, 17.10

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 17.04 desktop installed.
And I noticed that Ubuntu has just announced their new version (17.10). However, when I'm trying to open `update-manager`, it just tells me that I have the newest version.

Also, when I type the `sudo do-release-upgrade` command on the terminal, it tells me the same thing (`No new release found.`)

Is there any reasons for that, and what can I do? or should I just wait for that version, to get to the server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Be Patient**

This happens every six months with the next release of Ubuntu.

Availability does not begin at 00:01 local time. It happens worldwide at once...***after* the mirrors are updated**. So go about your normal life.

Due to [phased updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates) and the system-to-system variation of apt's normal checking for updates, **you may not get notification of a new release for a few days**.

- If you still don't get notification, check your **Software & Updates Control Panel** settings. Some users forget that they disabled new-release notifications, or enabled only LTS-release notifications.

There is wide, friendly **disagreement on whether upgrading or reinstalling is "best"**. Both are thoroughly tested. Both work. They are a matter of user preference, with the following caveats:

- Backup your data before doing either.
- If you upgrade, uninstall *all* software from non-Ubuntu sources (including PPAs) - they cause most upgrade failures.

Upgrading to a new release is **different from Debian**. Use the Ubuntu release-upgrade tool (`do-release-upgrade`). Following Debian instructions (apt dist-upgrade) will install new packages...in your older release.

If you are offered a **partial upgrade**, refuse it...which will abort the upgrade entirely and return you to the older release of Ubuntu. Your upgrade is broken, usually because of non-Ubuntu packages on your system. Disable those sources, uninstall those packages, and then try the release-upgrade again.

If you use **proprietary or compiled drivers** (like for some video cards), you may need to recompile or to install updated versions to match your new kernel. Make sure you have those instructions on hand before starting the release-upgrade.

Comment: Phased updates presumably doesn't apply to upgrades (that wiki article talks about the -proposed pocket)? Or where's the documentation that says it does?

Answer (score 5):

This whole process of getting all up and ready to go may take a bit time.

Anyways i would rather suggest you do a clean install of 17.10 instead of upgrading. Simply because too much has changed.

The ISO file can already be downloaded at http://releases.ubuntu.com/artful/

A short snip from the list of changes:

- The Ubuntu Desktop now uses GNOME instead of Unity.
- On supported systems, Wayland is now the default display server. The older display server is still available: just choose Ubuntu on Xorg from the cog on the log in screen.
- GDM has replaced LightDM as the default display manager. The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7.

([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes))

Comment: oh wow realy?? thank you very much for your advice, I will consider a fresh install.

Comment: @user6516763 Yes, lightdm is no longer the usual login and desktop manager it is gdm3 now and unity changes to gnome 3.xx. So pretty big changes in the overall System.

Comment: yes, I understand, but the problem is that I have a lot of programs and files on my laptop, a fresh install is a little bit hard, but I think I will do it anyway if you say so, I trust you :)

Comment: I can hear you I have the same on my machine, loads of programs, everything is settled, I'm actually in the process of doing a backup before I do anything. And to add to it, sometimes a fresh start can be quite good :)

Comment: A fresh install is several magnitudes more difficult than fixing the OP's minor issue on the currently running system.

Comment: @karl Richer so you suggest he simply upgrades from 17.04 up to 17.10? And that is worth a downvote?

Comment: @Videonauth I might be missing something, so correct me if I'm wrong: Ubuntu is a well maintained system and changes in Ubuntu will probably be handled well. The OP originally wanted to upgrade, but now likes the idea of making fresh install - I'm intervening in order make sure that the best information is provided. An upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 is automatic and basically one command. A fresh installation requires a lot of things to consider and is a potential source for numerous mistakes. I'd say it's a last resort for severe system failure/breakage and has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @KarlRichter And you thought of the complications which can occur, when switching lightdm which he has currently installed to gdb3 and unity7 to gnome? Well I can tell you I even tested it in VM with a fresh installed 17.04 and it didn't went well on a VM and I seriously doubt it will go better with a fully customized and fleged out system.

Comment: I'm upgrading since 12.04 and don't recall any major problems. I crashed a few systems over time when I doing things I knew were risky and know the drill. I really don't see how the two approaches upgrade and re-installation can be seen as alternatives to get the next available version. At least one should try to upgrade first and then re-installation is always an option.

Comment: I did too, from 15.10 till 17.04 but all where same desktop manager and the same desktop (lightdm/unity/X-11). Now it changes under the hood to (wayland/gdb3/gnome3).

Comment: I concur with the fresh install approach. The only reason I ever do an upgrade is so that I can support those who do, and never on a production system. (Of course I don't consider installing an OS an onerous task, for those who do, perhaps upgrading is more attractive)